# Javafx getSource() from KeyEvent

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I'm trying to get the source of my KeyEvent (in my case a TextField). I can print it out by using `e.getSource().toString()` which prints the String `TextField[id=molarMass, styleClass=text-input text-field]` but I only want to get the `TextFieldID` so I can use my method for other TextFields too and not only for this one.

Code:

```
public void correctTextField(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getSource().toString());
    if (e.getCode() != KeyCode.BACK_SPACE && !e.getCode().isArrowKey()) {
        int caretPosition = molarMass.getCaretPosition();
         molarMass.setText(DataUse.testForOnlyNumbers(molarMass.getText()));
        molarMass.positionCaret(caretPosition);
    }
}
```

`correctTextField` is used by a TextField everytime a key is pressed and I want to use the specific `TextFieldID` instead of using `molarMass` in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the source to a Node and get the ID from there.

For example:

```
Node n = (Node)event.getSource();
String id = n.getId();

//Do your logic....
```

Or you could cast to TextField if you are sure it's only going to be that....

Comment: Thank you. That was actually way easier than I imagined.
The easiest solution:

`TextField origin= ((TextField) e.getSource());`